# High cardinal Categorical features into numerics

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-processing

In most of the Academic examples, we used to convert categorical features using `get_dummies` or `OneHotEncoder`. Lets say I want to use `Country` as a feature and in the dataset we have 100 unique countries. When we apply `get_dummies` on country we will get 100 columns and model will be trained with 100 country columns plus other features.

Lets say, we have deployed this model into production, and we received only 10 countries. When we pre-process the data by using `get_dummies`, then model will fail predict because "Number of features model trained is not matching with the features passed" as we are passing 10 country columns plus other features.

I came across below article, where we can calculate score using Supervised ratio, Weight of evidence. But how to calculate the score when we want to predict the target in production, which country need to be assigned to right number.

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/08/include-high-cardinality-attributes-predictive-model.html

Can you please help me to understand how to handle such scenarios?

Comment: For high cardinality categorical features it's better to use CatBoost - gradient boosting that accepts this type of data, or make Target Encoding as preprocessing. It usually gives better quality.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do.

1. Apply OHE after combining your training set and test/validation set data not before that.
2. Skip OHE and apply StandardScaler because "If a feature has a variance that is orders of magnitude larger that others, it might dominate the objective function and make the estimator unable to learn from other features correctly as expected."

I usually try second option when, I've  multiple unique feature in any categorical dataset and can cause my test/validation set
Feel free to correct me.